# How to show Emails sent from a Case in the history?

Tags: email-alert, activityhistory

I am sending emails from Cases using email alerts for various reasons. I would like for a copy of the sent email to be stored within the history of the Case somewhere. How can I do that ? I know there's a way with emails which have been sent manually from within the Case, but I'm not sure how to do it with emails sent via email alerts.

I have found this solution (from 2019) :
https://www.salesforceben.com/sending-and-logging-email-alerts-as-an-activity-heres-our-solution/

Has there since been a new solution implemented in Salesforce ?

Comment: consider using [UnofficialSF.com SendBetter Email (for Flow)](https://unofficialsf.com/send-better-email-flow-action/) in lie of Email Alerts; these can be saved as Activities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are triggering the alerts via flow you can also create an EmailMessage record that ties back to the case. You can query for the email template so that all the subject and body text is up to date with the template.

Comment: oh ok - I need to learn about that. I haven't worked with that at all. I figured there was functionality I wasn't aware of which went into this. I'll look into it now. Is it essentially like an Activity that gets added to the history of the Case once created ? From I'm looking at so far it looks like I can create a full copy of the email, including the template, not just the plain text...? Thank you very much ! @Brian

Comment: @Zoom_v I'm not fully aware of how EmailMessage and Activity records are connected but yes it would be very similar to that where you would see the email in the feed thread. It a way of adding a "paper trail" to the emails in salesforce. So by no way would creating an EmailMessage actually trigger the sending of an email, it is just the documentation of it.